# How to do 3 layer flattening nested json to dataframe?

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe, nested

For example the JSON is :

```
{
    "samples": [
        {
            "sample_id": "A2434",
            "start": "1664729482",
            "end": "1664729482",
            "parts": [
                {
                    "name": "123",
                    "start": "1664736682",
                    "end": "1618688700",
                    "fail": ""
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want the df and columns like below :

sample_id,start,end,parts.name,parts.start,parts.end,parts.fail

Answer (score 3):

Using [json.normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html)

```
df = pd.json_normalize(
    data=data["samples"],
    record_path="parts",
    record_prefix="parts.",
    meta=["sample_id", "start", "end"]
).drop(columns="parts.name")

print(df)

  parts.start   parts.end parts.fail sample_id       start         end
0  1664736682  1618688700                A2434  1664729482  1664729482
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`df.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) to get the separate item in a list on a row, and use `agg(pd.Series)` to convert key, value pairs in a dictionary to columns and rows, respectively.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data['samples'])
df[['parts.start','parts.end','parts.fail']] = df['parts'].explode().agg(pd.Series)
df.drop('parts', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
     sample_id  start   end      parts.name parts.start parts.end   parts.fail
0   A2434   1664729482  1664729482   123    1664736682  1618688700
```

Comment: This one fails if i try to add parts.name column :

df = pd.DataFrame(data1['samples'])
    df[['parts.name','parts.start', 'parts.end', 'parts.fail']] = df['parts'].explode(). \
                                                         agg(pd.Series).iloc[:, 1:]
    df.drop('parts', axis=1, inplace=True)

Comment: sorry it was my bad, I've updated the answer

Comment: if I try to use name in df its failing, Try this one :
df = pd.DataFrame(data['samples'])
    df[['parts.name', 'parts.start', 'parts.end']] = df['parts'].explode().agg(pd.Series)
    df.drop('parts', axis=1, inplace=True)
    print(df)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pd.read_json()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) to unpack the JSON to a Dataframe. You can then use [`pd.json_normalize()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html#pandas.json_normalize) as required on the generated columns to get the more nested data out.